# tkinter insert and delete function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have started experimenting with tkinter a little. Right now im trying to build a simple calculator and for that I used the `delete` and `insert` function to clear the `Entry`.

This is the command I used:

```
t1.delete(1.0, 'end')
```

My question: What is the meaning of '1.0' and the 'end'?

Comment: From tk doc : The "1.0" here is the position where to insert the text, and can be read as "line 1, character 0". This refers to the first character of the first line. Historically, especially on Unix, programmers tend to think about line numbers as 1-based and character positions as 0-based.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter Text widget has `delete(first, last=None)` method to delete the characters at the index of first, or within the `range of (first, last)` from the text box.

Visit this link:  [what is the meaning of '1.0' and the 'end'](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-clear-tkinter-text-box-widget/#:%7E:text=Tkinter%20Text%20widget%20has%20delete,the%20first%20position%20is%20deleted.)